# Can't create/write to file '/opt/new/abc.csv' (Errcode: 13)

Tags: mysql

I am getting errorcode while trying to dump CSV from JAVA using mysql query SELECT INTO OUTFILE.
I already appended the lines:

```
/opt/new/ r,
  /opt/new/** rw,
```

to /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld and restarted it but still no effect.
I also tried changing the permissions of my folder to 777 but still same error is coming.
Could anyone suggest.Platform I am using is UBUNTU

Comment: the user under which mysql runs needs to have rw permissions to that folder

Comment: permissions is set to 777 for this folder

Comment: then try to write in another folder like `/home/user` and see if it works